# Disabling right click button only for a specific HTML code

Tags: iframe, right-click

I have this code:

```
    <div id="frameContainer" style="overflow:hidden;"> 
    <iframe oncontextmenu="return false;" src="http://youtube.com" scrolling="yes" style="width: 790px; height: 500px; margin-        top: -120px;"> 
    </iframe> 
    </div> 
    </div>
```

And what I want to do is to disable the right click mouse button whenever a user clicks inside of that frame.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As the rest of the web will tell you, it's usually very bad practice to disable right clicking. However it is possible by adding this javascript event: `oncontextmenu="return false;"` to the iframe.

Comment: I've updated my code to show you how I tried to do what you said; it doesn't work for some reason, I can still right click on the iframe freely.

Comment: In which case I think that means the youtube embed doesn't want you disabling right click. There's a slim chance that if you put the iframe within a right clicking disabled div it will work, but you may never be able to disable right clicking on the actual video.

Answer (score 0):

to disable right click button in your website we add in the label body the following attribute below in the body oncontextmenu="return false"